# On startup app is going crash in android wix react-native-navigation drawer , but working fine on iOS

Tags: android, react-native, crash, velo, wix-react-native-navigation

I am using react-native-navigation(v1) of wix.App is going to crash on startup without any error message on Android , but working fine in iOS.

```
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
             screen: 'Home',

                navigatorStyle:{navBarHidden:true,
                                disabledBackGesture:true,
                                hideBackButtonTitle: true,
                                navBarBackgroundColor:'#63DCAD',
                                navBarButtonColor:'#FFF',
                                navBarTextColor:'#FFF'},

    },
    drawer: {
        left: {
            screen: 'menu',
        },
        disableOpenGesture: true
    }
});
```

Comment: if app is crashing your best shot is to open android studio and use logcat to find the reason to crash. if you provide your crash log people can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it happens due to android configuration.

Have you added the following in android `MainApplication.java` file:

```
@Override 
public String getJSMainModuleName() {   
     return "index"; 
}
```

If you are using `index.js` as your entry point instead of `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` (it is the default since React Native 0.49).

I hope it help you.